# Show $BV[a, b]$ is not dense in $B[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Show that $BV[a, b]$ is not dense in $B[a, b]$ under the metric $||f||_\infty$.

I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Comment: Weierstrass Approximation theorem is for continuous functions isn't it ?

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad

Comment: I guess that $BV$ is closed in $B$. If this is true, and if you can prove it (of course! :-) ) then you are finished because clearly there exist bounded functions which are not of bounded variation such as $\sin(1/x)$ (in a neighborhood of $0$).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro But $BV$ is not closed in $B$, consider $x \mapsto x^2 \cdot \cos(1/x) \cdot \chi_{]1/n,1]}(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestion: consider the function $1_\mathbb{Q}$ which takes the value 1 at every rational and 0 at every irrational.  Show that if $\|f - 1_\mathbb{Q}\|_\infty < 1/2$ then $f$ has unbounded variation.

Comment: Great example, +1.